# How to transfer data between pages in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to transfer data back to my class component from `DropDownItem` component and I can't do it with props.
in this example, I want to transfer `props.product` of the clicked item to my App Component.
could anyone tell me what is the best way to do it?
thanks in advance.

when I'm clicking on a drop down option I want to show it as an instance in my 
main class component.
I already tried to create a special component for this purpose, but it makes the code really complicated.

```jsx
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      products: []
    }
  }

  async fetchDevices() {

    const url = 'my url';
    const response = await fetch(url, { method: 'GET', headers: headers });
    const data = await response.json()
    this.setState({ products: data.value })
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchDevices();
  }

  render() {
    const productItems = this.state.products.map((productValue, index) => {
      return (<DropDownItem key={index} product={productValue.name} />)
    })

    return (
      <div>

        {this.state.products[0] && Array.isArray(this.state.products) ?
          <div>
            <DropdownComponent
              isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen}
              toggle={this.toggle}
              product={productItems}
            />
          </div> :
          <div>loading...</div>}
        <p></p>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default App

function DropDownItem(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <DropdownItem onClick={() => console.log("selected product", props.product)}>
        {props.product}</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem divider />
    </div>
  )
}
export default DropDownItem
```

I want to show the selected item in my App component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general rules for data transfer between components are:

- To transfer from parent component (`App` in your case) to child (`DropDownItem`) use `props`
- To transfer from child to parent (what you want to do) - use callbacks with relevant parameters

Example (not tested, just to show idea)

```
// App component
...
selectDropDownItem(item) {
    this.setState({selectedItem: item});
}

render () {
    return 
    // ...
    <DropdownComponent
      isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} 
      toggle={this.toggle}
      product={productItems}
      selectItemCallback={this.selectDropDownItem.bind(this)}/>
    //...

// DropDownItem component

function DropDownItem (props) {

 return (
<div>

// bind to props.product so when called props.product will be passed as argument
<DropdownItem onClick={props.selectItemCallback.bind (null, props.product)}>
{props.product}</DropdownItem>
<DropdownItem divider/>
</div>
)  
}

export default DropDownItem
```

General idea is that you pass callback from your parent down to child. When child needs to communicate to parent it just calls callback passed in props and pass required data as arguments to this callback (in your example this can be selected item)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

In your example the this.props is outside the class component so maybe it should work with props only?
I understand the use of callback here, but how practically can I transfer the specific props back?

Comment: Props are known to parent and read only on childern's side. So I think you want to psss not props but some data which your child component produced. For example, `DropdownItem` will present items to user. When user selects one, `onClick` event handler is called. It is bound to `selectItemCallback` callback received as part of props. `selectItemCallback` is called with argument `props.product` which is selected product and received on parent's component side as argument for `selectDropDownItem`

Comment: It seems that selectItemCallback is undefined.
Do you know how can I fix that?